# Pandas, assign object name using index strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using sample data:

```
Product = [Galaxy_8, Galaxy_Note_9, Galaxy_Note_10, Galaxy_11]
```

I would like to create 4 data frames, each of the data frames contains respective sales information.
The problem is I would like to use index method to create data frames, for instance,

**Expected output is**:

```
Galaxy_8 = pd.DataFrame()
Galaxy_Note_9 = Pd.DataFrame()
Galaxy_Note_10 = pd.DataFrame()
Galaxy_11 = pd.DataFrame()
```

Imagine if the product list counts beyond 200, what is the most efficient way to achieve the desired outcome?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sample list is like,

```
Product = ['Galaxy_8', 'Galaxy_Note_9', 'Galaxy_Note_10','Galaxy_11']
```

Then you can try like:

```
for var in Product:
  globals()[var] = pd.DataFrame()
```